# How to match CSS color to PNG color

Tags: html, css, image, colors, color-profile

So I have a png file with a solid blue color. If I open it in any paint program (have tried multiple ones) it says that the color of the entire square is rgba(126,234,242,1.0). But when I open the PNG file in a html-page, and tries to make an identical square with pure CSS, the color comes out just slightly differently, even though I'm setting the color to the same exact rgba value. How is this possible? And what can I do to match the color of the CSS square to the PNG-square?

HTML:

```
<img src="blue.png"/>
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(126,234,242,1.0);
}
```

Image:

[image]

I have tried to research this subject a bit, and I believe that it has something to do with color profiles. As far as I can understand, sRGB is the default color profile for everthing web-related. However, I've made sure that Krita, the paint application I'm using, is set to use sRGB, and I've both tried checking and not checking the box that says "embed sRGB profile" when exporting the PNG file from Krita. The two squares looked different in both cases.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

As suggested by Temani Afif, I used the color picker in chrome to look at the rgb-values. 
First square (PNG): rgba(165,230,241,1)
Second square: rgba(126,234,242,1)

So is the correct approach just to pick the color in a browser instead of in a paint application? And I still don't really understand why the colors are displayed differently.

EDIT 2:

I thought it might be helpful to explain my real-world context of this problem. I have a menu designed with CSS in my javascript game. The menu has a PNG background, and buttons whose color is defined in CSS. I also have a "concept" PNG, where the entire menu with the buttons are drawn over the background. In the real html menu, the background looks identical to how it looks in the concept PNG, and I would like the buttons to look the same as well. Just color-picking the rgb-values from the concept PNG doesn't work, as shown with example above. Doing the workaround from my first edit works for my monitor, but doesn't for other monitors.

EDIT 3:

The workaround works for different monitors with the same computer. With another computer, the squares looks different again.

Comment: the rgba value is invalid here  ... the last one should be the opacity (0 to 1) .. inspect the element and pick the color from the browser

Comment: Try processing the PNG files through optipng or pngcrush (there are online versions too).

Comment: @Salman Well, that made the two squares the same color at least. But what I actually would like is the CSS color to be the same as the PNG was before. My thought was that this maybe was achievable by some color profile setting in CSS, but I'd assume that it's impossible. The "workaround" I presented in my edit achieved this for my monitor, but on another computer the colors still differed.

Comment: @Istlemin it could have been the gamma or SRGB information embedded inside the PNG, and optipng/pngcrush removed it. I think different browsers might honor or ignore this information, you could end up with images that appear different on different browsers. I would suggest that you strip all such information from PNGs, then match the colors in CSS accordingly.